# Hiding a panel on click of RadioButtonList using JQuery

Tags: jquery, .net

I have a asp:RadioButtonList and one panel

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="someList" runat="server"    
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radioList">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Don't Know" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>                                        
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
This is panel 1
</asp:Panel>
```

When I click on Yes panel should be displayed when I click on "No" and "Don't Know" the panel should be hidden.
Help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I did it using radiobutton , but not with radiobuttonlist !!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var panel = $("#Panel1"); 
$("input[name='cboVisibility']").change(function () { 
  if ($(this).val() == 1) panel.show(); 
  else panel.hide() 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KevQv/

Comment: it's rather `<%= this.Panel1.ClientID %>` :)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

          var panel = $("#Panel1");

          $("#cboVisibility").change(function () {

              if ($(this).val() == 1)

                  panel.show();

              else

                  panel.hide()



          })

    </script>

Comment: @Undefined :
<table id="cboVisibility" class="Normal">

 <tr>

  <td><input id="cboVisibility_0" type="radio" name="cboVisibility" value="0" /><label for="cboVisibility_0">Check-In Date</label></td><td><input id="cboVisibility_1" type="radio" name="cboVisibility" value="1" /><label for="cboVisibility_1">Book Date</label></td><td><input id="cboVisibility_2" type="radio" name="cboVisibility" value="2" /><label for="cboVisibility_2">Other Date</label></td>

 </tr>

</table>

    <div id="Panel1" style="background-color: Gray; height: 300px;

        display: none">

 

    

</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
  var panel = $("#<%= this.Panel1.ClientID %>")  
  $(".radioList").change(function(){
           if($(this).val() == 1)
              panel.show();
           else
              panel.hide()

    })
```